# Project keeps loading an non existant NIB file!

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, xib, nib

Good evening,

I created a class which inherits from UIViewController and i created a nib file, where i set up my view. After that i decided to set the view programmatically as it is more configurable... The problem is that even though i deleted the .XIB file, I cleaned the project, I deleted the class and remade it, it keeps loading a non existant NIB file... What should i do?

Thank you!

L_Sonic

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app off the device or resetting the simulator prior to doing a clean/rebuild?

Comment: answer it to get credit! That helped :D thank you! I only lost 3 hours of my time....:(

Comment: If only you'd asked sooner. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the resources don't get flushed correctly when they're updated/removed. As such, you might need to delete the app off the device or reset the simulator prior to doing a clean/rebuild.

Comment: Can anyone advise about how this works in production? Should we avoid at all costs deleting nibs once released to the App Store?

Comment: @Max This does not apply to production. It only happens when you deploy from xcode. Xcode never deletes files on the simulator or device.